# Convert Unicode (e.g. 1f564) to Emoji in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, emoji

How do you convert unicode emoji stored as a string (e.g. `1f564`) to an emoji that could be placed on a UILabel?

```
let myString = "1f564"
```

I've seen the use of the escape character but I can't insert variables to replace the characters.

```
let flag = "\u{1f1e9}\u{1f1ea}"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works.  I don't know if there is anything more direct:

```
let myStr = "1f564"
let str = String(UnicodeScalar(Int(myStr, radix: 16)!)!)
```

Comment: Will this work if the unicode is part of a large string with other normal text?

Comment: @Nitesh, no. In order for this to work you need to extract the hex digits from the larger string, put them into their own string and create the Unicode character from that.