# Swift String literal for unicode character is wrong

Tags: swift, unicode, string-literals

I am trying to pass a unicode character from Swift to a UIWebPage. The String is coming in from the server as `"\\2020"` so that the escaped version should be `"\2020"` (the dagger symbol). When it is passed in however, it is becoming `"2020"`. Is it breaking in the javascript or before it gets there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To represent the character in Swift you must use this kind of interpolation:

```
let dagger = "\u{2020}"
```

Comment: So, can I do this: if let codeStr:String = String(m.bullet!.characters.dropFirst()){
                    
                    let unicodeStr:String = "\\u{\(codeStr)}"
                }

Comment: @LeeProbert, see this answer if you have `"2020"` in a `String var` and want to convert it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32555223/1630618