# Remove \\ from \\u{1F60A} to get result \u{1F60A}

Tags: swift, string, emoji

I'm getting string like this from my api `\\u{1F60A}`, But I'm not able to display emoji with this. I need this type format `\u{1F60A}` to show emoji on the UILabel. So with 2 `"\\"`  I'm not able to show emoji in the screen and need to remove 1 `"\"` from string.
I've tried below codes to remove "\" and have only 1 "\". But the result was either  `\\u{1F60A}`(with \ slashes) or `u{1F60A}` (with no slashes).

```
let text  = "\\u{1F60A}"

text = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)  // producing the result "u{1F60A}"

text = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\\\", with: "\\", options: .literal, range: nil) // producing the result "\\u{1F60A}"
```

I'm not able to display the emoji in the text.
I'm using xcode 10.2 and swift 4.2

Any help appreciated. TIA

Comment: The string literal `"\\u{1F60A}"` contains the escape sequence `"\\"`, which represents one backslash character.

Comment: Yes but it not working. If I use "\u{1F60A}" then only emoji is displayed but if I use "\\u{1F60A}" then emoji is not displayed

Comment: That is the way it's supposed to work. `"\u{1F60A}"` is one Unicode character long, `"\\u{1F60A}"` is nine characters long.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37938823/1187415.

Comment: The problem is what I'm getting as string from api is "\\u{1F60A}" but I need to convert it into "\u{1F60A}" so that it should show emoji and I'm not able to convert it.

Comment: If the string is those ten characters, you need to parse it yourself and convert to the proper number. No amount of removing backslashes will help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but not able to parse that's why I've asked question regarding this.

Comment: You could use a regular expression to extract the bit between then braces, then convert that to an integer, then convert that to the corresponding unicode character.